# MapViews in Fragments API <11.

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have been researching this for a while now. I actually have 2 working applications that implement a map in a fragment. Each application uses a different approach. Wondering which is better if any. I am also wondering if i am just behind on this and maybe there is a better way that i have not found yet.

The 2 approaches.

One uses LocalActivityManager which is depreciated.

The other approach is detailed [here](https://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/howto-actionbarsherlock-mapfragment-listfragment) using a Exchanger to coordinate between Activity and Map

The first method has the drawback of already being depreciated. 
I thought i saw a problem with the second method but i am unable to find it again.

Is there any benefit to one method or the other. Or is there something else that i should be looking into?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this](https://github.com/petedoyle/android-support-v4-googlemaps) library (android-support-v4-googlemaps)

> A port of the Android Compatibility package which makes FragmentActivity extend MapActivity. This is a hack to make it possible to use a MapView in a Fragment.

Moreover i use it instead of Compatibility package to build ActionBarSherlock - so i have map + fragments + action bar.

Comment: Yes this library from petedoyle is what i use in the second implementation. If you see the instructions at the top it actually tells you how to properly use the support google map lib with ABS. You actually import the library from petedoyles github. The second implementation is what i am using for now unless someone has a better approach.

Comment: The code in [this example](https://xrigau.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/howto-actionbarsherlock-mapfragment-listfragment/) uses the same thing. I think he has a listview in another fragment with the ABS. I am just trying to figure out if there is a better way.